# Where, best, should I place my add_action and function codes in the function.php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

As a relative newbie to creating WordPress Themes from scratch, I still have quite a lot to learn.

I am currently 'learning on the job' and one of the questions I keep asking myself, is 'Does it matter whether I place the add_action before the function or not?'

I have just integrated the WooCommerce functionality by modifying my code as following:

I see a lot of coding set out as follows:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommerce_support' );
function woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
```

That said, I see a lot of other coding as set out below:

```
function woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommerce_support' );
}
```

Are there any pros and cons with either approaches or is it simply a developer's preference in terms of how they wish to organise their code?

Comment: The second block seems wrong to me, because you call the woocommerce_support() again and again - have never seen it or use it like that. From my experience until now you create a function(in your case `woocommerce_support()`) and then for that function to be called you add it on an action or filter etc depends what the function does. [Here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/difference-between-filter-and-action-hooks) is a reference for the difference between filter or action.

Comment: **The second snippet is wrong and does nothing…** The first one will work because your function **`woocommerce_function()`** is correctly hooked in **`after_setup_theme`** hook (meaning that is called or executed when **`after_setup_theme`** hook is thrown).

Comment: Thank you both, for this insight. I thought the 1st coding was the correct approach but thought I would double check in case there were performance related issues etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with php coding some more, I have gained a further understanding of its functions and how the coding platform works.

Whilst there are a few exceptions, I can see that the `add_action` needs to be placed outside of the function's curly brackets.  I have yet to see a difference with placing the `add_action` before or after the connected function.  As a personal preference, this is how I would typically set out my code:

```
function woocommerce_support() { 
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommerce_support' ); //This line should not be placed within the above curly brackets '{}'
```

I have commented my above example, just in case anyone is new to php and had the same query when starting out.

Thought I would answer my own question; as to ensure nobody spends their valuable time answering a question I now have an answer to (and to also 'close' this question).

If anyone has information that counters my answer, I welcome such input.  Whilst I now have a better understanding of how php works, I still have a lot to learn! :-)

Comment: Putting the add_action inside the function is just plain wrong. Also, with newer versions of PHP you can use anonymous functions just like in JS which I'd say is preferred in this case as the function is never used again.

Comment: For clarity to both myself and others, are you agreeing with my coding layout - In the sense that the add_action is outside the curly brackets (This is deemed outside the function, right?)  I am not familiar with 'anonymous functions' as of yet, so cannot really comment on this aspect.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Yes, the add action should be outside the curly brackets. Anonymous functions are just unnamed functions you pass directly to the add action call. They're easy to use, just google it.

Comment: Great!  Thanks for your input, powerbuoy!

Answer (score 0):

I was on the same page, but as @Craig said we cannot put the *add_action()* inside the body of the function, because it won't work there.
But we can put add_action() either before or after the function depending upon the choice.
Here is what I tried (add_action before the function),

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'simple_theme_support');

function simple_theme_support(){ //function for featured image

    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
}
```

(add_action after the function)

```
function simple_theme_support(){ //function for featured image

    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'simple_theme_support');
```

in both cases, I got the same output.